# NodeJS setTimeOut - How to run callback before delay time exceeded

Tags: game-loop, node.js

I'm developing a card game server.
I want to do this :
While server process a turn for players, players have 20 seconds to do something. If players send a request to server within 20 secs, timer will stop and the callback will fire.

I'm doing like this :

self.tables[table.id].currentTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    callback();
}, 20*1000);

How should I run the callback before delay time exceeded ?

Answer (score 1):

Just stop the timer and then call the callback yourself.

```
clearTimeout(self.tables[table.id].currentTimer);
callback();
```